# my handmade ELF file, 'mov eax,1' 'ret' came out an error of segmentation fault

Tags: linux, assembly, elf

I am inspired by [link](http://scheme2006.cs.uchicago.edu/11-ghuloum.pdf).And I want to implement an C compiler step by step.This is my first step to implement an main function in C.
Here is my code.I use the function 'elf_write' to write an elf file by hand,but when I run the generated ELF file,came out an error of segmentation fault(the Linux version of my computer is Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GUN/Linux 3.2.0-80-generic x86_64)):

```
    void elf_write(FILE *elf)
    {
        unsigned char code[] = {
            //0x55,//push ebp
            0xb8,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,//mov eax,1
            //0x89,0xe5,//mov ebp,esp
            //0x5d,//pop ebp
            0xc3//ret
        };

        uint64_t entry = 0x400000;
        Elf64_Ehdr ehdr = {
            .e_ident = {
                ELFMAG0, ELFMAG1, ELFMAG2, ELFMAG3,
                ELFCLASS64,
                ELFDATA2LSB,
                EV_CURRENT,
                ELFOSABI_SYSV,
            },
            .e_type = ET_EXEC,
            .e_machine = EM_X86_64,
            .e_version = EV_CURRENT,
            .e_entry = entry + sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr) + sizeof(Elf64_Phdr),
            .e_phoff = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr),
            .e_ehsize = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr),
            .e_phentsize = sizeof(Elf64_Phdr),
            .e_phnum = 1
        };
        Elf64_Phdr phdr_text = {
            .p_type = PT_LOAD,
            //.p_offset = sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr) + 2*sizeof(Elf64_Phdr),
            .p_flags = PF_X | PF_R,
            .p_vaddr = entry,
            .p_filesz = sizeof(code),
            .p_memsz = sizeof(code),
            .p_align = 0x200000
        };
        fwrite(&ehdr, sizeof(ehdr), 1, elf);
        fwrite(&phdr_text, sizeof(phdr_text), 1, elf);
        fwrite(code, sizeof(code), 1, elf);
    }
```

when I change the code to this,it executed perfectly and print "ABCDE" in the terminal.

```
    unsigned char code[] = {
        0xb8,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,//mov rax,1
        0xba,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,//mov rdx,12
        0xbe,0x9a,0x00,0x40,0x00,//mov rsi,0x4000b0
        0xbf,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,//mov rdi ,1
        0x0f,0x05,               //syscall
        0xb8,0x3c,0x00,0x00,0x00,//mov rax,60
        0xbf,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,//mov rdi ,0
        0x0f,0x05,               //syscall
        0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x0A//ABCDE
    };
```

Comment: which instruction does it segfault on?  And have you looked at http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html?

Comment: There are only two instructions and I don't know how to catch the bug,since the file is handmade,objdump and other tools seems not working.And I have a brief view of this famous article.

Comment: I am inspired by [link](http://scheme2006.cs.uchicago.edu/11-ghuloum.pdf).And I want to implement an C compiler step by step.This is my first step to implement an main function.

Comment: Use `gdb` and run your file.  It should stop at the point you get a segfault.  BTW, you could just write a compiler that emits asm code and feeds it to `as` and `ld`, the way gcc does.  Then the usual tools would make object files for you.  I assume you already know that, and want to do it yourself anyway.

Comment: In the code that doesn't work the last instruction is a `ret`. Where do you expect `ret` is going to return to? Compare that to using syscall 60 to exit in the code that works.

Comment: Yeah I just saw the title again and realized the same thing.  At the ELF entry point, there's no return address on the stack, just argc and argv (and the environment).  See the System V ABI docs (links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)).  As I understand it, Windows *does* put a return address on the stack on entry (the address of an exit-process DLL function), but Linux doesn't do that.

Comment: Thank you all,,you are right! I change  'ret' to syscall 60,and no error came out.